# Segmentation error in C after printing a method in a for loop

Tags: c

I have a problem when trying to print the numbers in the n given row of Pascal's triangle in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int n, k;
    double result1, result2;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    scanf("%d", &k);

    result2 = knumberinnrowofpascal(8, 4);
    printf("%f\n", result2);

    int i = 0;
    for (i; i<n; i++) {
        result2 = knumberinnrowofpascal(n, i);
        printf("%f\n", result2);
    }

    return 0;
}

int combinations(int n, int k) // calculates combinations of (n,k).
{
    if (k == 0)
        return 1;
    else if (k > n)
        return 0;
    else
        return (combinations(n - 1, k) + combinations(n - 1, k - 1));
}

int knumberinnrowofpascal(int n, int k)
{
    double rightmultipier, leftmultiplier, result;
    rightmultipier = (double)(n + 1 - k) / k;
    leftmultiplier = (double)combinations(n, k - 1);
    result = (double)leftmultiplier * rightmultipier;
    return result;
}
```

The function "knumberinnrowofpascal" works, I've tested it above (the 4th element in the 8th row ). The problem is when I try to print these results in a for loop.

Comment: Provide code for the function `knumberinnrowofpascal()` so that we can run the code.!!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. I believe you that your function works, I'd just like to verify that as part of a normal debugging process.

Comment: `int i=0; for(i;i<=n;i++)` Don't you think there is issue in your for loop.

Comment: post the function `knumberinnrowofpascal`

Comment: @George it is `int`

Comment: And what do you experience when you say you have a problem?

Comment: @AditiRawat: There's nothing inherently wrong with that loop. `i<=n` is often a code smell, true.

Comment: Sorry i didn't copy the text correctly, forgot to include the functions.

Comment: Divide by 0 is occuring in the function..`combinations(10,1)`

Comment: ^^^^^^ when k=0

Comment: @coderredoc: And that's exactly why we cannot accept statements like "the function works" at face value.

Comment: 'rightmultipier = (double)(n + 1 - k) / k;' ..... '/k'

Comment: Stepping through with your debugger would have identified your divide-by-zero issues first time round:(

Comment: @AndyG Maybe i should have been more clear . What do you think will be value of `i` in this case : `int i=0; i;`

Comment: `return combinations(n-1,k) ...` looks like a bit of infinite recursion may be happening there. (well, until n underflows to become positive, but I think it segfaults before reaching there)

Comment: 'The function "knumberinnrowofpascal" works, I've tested it' - no.  You tried one test case. Boundary values, like 0, and illegal values, eg negative, should form part of testing.

Comment: @AditiRawat: It doesn't matter what that value is so long as it's not undefined to access it.

Comment: Ok I understand now where I was wrong, I added a case in the knumberinnrowofpascal function to return 1 if k = 0 .

Comment: @AndyG The loop needs to run from `i`  equals to `0` to `n`. And writing `int i=0; i;` implies `i` is not necessarily `0`. https://ideone.com/tPC41L

Comment: @AditiRawat why are you trying to print &i and not i?

Comment: @AndyG Alright..sorry..my bad!

Answer (score 0):

```
rightmultipier = (double)(n + 1 - k) / k;
```

This will fail if k is 0. And even if it didn't, it would on the next row, because you would have infinite recursion there.

Change:

```
int i = 0;
for (i; i <= n; i++) {
```

to

```
int i;
for (i=1; i <= n; i++) {
```

I made two improvements there. I fixed the bug and moved the initialization to the for header.

Answer (score 0):

`return (combinations(n - 1, k) + combinations(n - 1, k - 1));`

when `k!=0` and `n<k`, you recurse with `combinations(n-1,k)`.  Decrementing `n` in this recursion does not change k!=0, and it certainly does not make n > k until it overflows, which means you are in a practically infinite recursion and it segfaults.